# How to convert a function of $x$ and $y$ into a function based in polar coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

[image]

How did my teacher get from $x^2(x^2+y^2)$ to $r\cdot r^2\cos^2(\theta)(r^2)$?

I'm looking into the equations put I'm still at a loss because those usually require just $x$ and $y$ values like R being equal to:

$r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In polar coordinates, $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$. The final $r$ is the Jacobian.

Comment: @player3236 wait so i just replace the x and ys with those things? it's that easy?

Comment: Almost. Since it's still a coordinate transform, you still need the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Example_2:_polar-Cartesian_transformation), and the integration bounds should also be changed.

Comment: @player3236 awesome! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of polar coordinates, we have that $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, can you take it from here?

Comment: wait so I just replace the x's with those things?

Comment: Yep, then you will probably need the identity $\sin^{2}(\theta)+\cos^{2}(\theta)=1$.